# Benefit of using gcc4 over gcc34?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, legacy

Is three any performance benefit of using gcc4 over gcc34 ?
Currently we are using gcc34 with old c runtime to support all old os. 
So is there any performance benefit of using gcc4 ?

Comment: That will depend a lot on your specific application. Just try it and benchmark.

Comment: ... lots of things. Plenty of stuff. There's just no way to know if it will be better for **your** specific code without trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Bench-marking tests run by RedHat for g++ (GCC-3.4.2) & g++ (GCC-4.x) on identical platform and enviornment,

For **Compilation Performance**:
gcc-4 is faster than gcc-3.4, by a significant margin.

For **Executable Performance**:
There is little difference between the two.

Check the bench-marking comparisons **[here](http://people.redhat.com/bkoz/benchmarks/)**

For your code & architecture, you will have to benchmark it to see if the results are similar.

Comment: They did use 4.0.0 though which obviously has no c++0x support it being itself not especially fresh. Especially move semantics can give you tremendous performance improvements, but then that's not done by just recompiling so probably not was meant. Since the STL was partially rewritten (move semantics; also I think some better algorithms) it could give some performance gains as well - though the STL was already a highly optimized bit of code, so probably not that much.

Comment: 3.4.2 is 7 years old next month. Nothing happened during that time?